# discord bot is showing online but doesnt show up need commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i keep getting the error "The application did not respond".

Yet my bot shows up as online on discord
and none of the new commands I made are showing up yet. However, the old ones I (currently deleted) are still there.

```
import { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';
import fs from 'fs';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]
});

client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = './src/commands';
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  import(`./src/commands/${file}`).then(commandModule => {
    client.commands.set(commandModule.default.data.name, commandModule.default);
  });
}

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
  if (!command) return;

  try {
    await command.execute(interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error executing that command.', ephemeral: true });
  }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: What are you trying to figure out? Without a clear question we can't give you an answer.

Comment: @NormalCoderPerson so im trying to build my discord bot to basically help me numerology, yet it when i implemented new code it never updated and it keeps giving me the error of **the application did not respond**

Comment: So you're asking how to resolve this error?

Comment: @NormalCoderPerson yes actually

Comment: Ok. I don't actually have knowledge in the area of Discord bot programming, just trying to help others who do be clear what this is about. Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: @NormalCoderPerson thats ok

Comment: Have you deployed your commands? If you create/delete commands, you should deploy them for Discord to see your changes. Check out [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#guild-commands) which gives an example of how to achieve that.

Comment: yes i even deleted the bot and made a new one, and now no commands are popping up and i even rewrote the code, it just shows that it is online in discord. and thats it @moonstar-x

Comment: How are you deploying you commands? Your code example does not show any of that.

Comment: @moonstar-x  `import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';
import { Routes } from 'discord-api-types/v9';
import fs from 'fs';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const commands = [];
const commandsPath = './src/commands';
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

`